# how to write puppet-rspec for dependent define?

Tags: ruby, rspec, puppet

I have a define like below,

```
define module::define1 (
  $path = undef,
  $someparam = undef,
  ...
) {

  unless defined(Define2[$someparam]) {
    fail("Please create define2[$someparam] first")
  }

  file { $path:
    ensure => directory,
  }
}
```

When I try to test the existence of file[$path] I am getting error "Please create define2[$someparam] first". But define2 is in another file.
How can I include define2 inside my define1's rspec scope?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are hitting a severe limitation of your manifest design. Expressing cross-dependencies through the `defined` function is very fragile and bound to lead to issues.

Have you considered replacing your checks with [constraints](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/ffrank/constraints)? (The module documentation also elaborates a bit on why `defined` is often a bad idea.)